# Adding to my current attr cx value when defining coordinates of my circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Given below is the code where I am defining where to plot dots on my graph. The problem is, the value I achieve through xMap is off by a little so I would like to add 10 points to it. However that isn't possible as xMap isn't a simple number value.

```
var dot = svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(data3)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("class", "dot")
.attr("r", 7)
.attr("cx", xMap)
.attr("cy", yMap)
.style("fill", "rgb(0,0,0)")
```

Given below is the code to arriving at xMap:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, 100])
.range([height, 0]);
var xValue = function(d) {return d.Score;}
var xMap = function(d) { return x(xValue(d));}
```

Ideally I would just like to say

```
.attr("cx", xMap + 5)
```

but that leads to the error "Error:  attribute cx: Expected length, "function(d) { re…"......"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following solution to solve your problem:

```
var dot = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data3)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("r", 7)
    .attr("cx", d => x(d.Score) + 5)
    .attr("cy", d => y(d.value))
    .style("fill", "black");
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally discouraged on Stack Overflow. Please explain your solution, including how it differs from the question and why your changes resolve the issue.

Comment: @Shadow: what needs to be explained about 1 line of code? a large simplification of the original code, is the OP unable to read the docs to learn why the solution works and why his code is over-complicated.

Comment: The one line of code (which spans over 8 lines) that you have does not clearly explain what you've done differently to the questioner. Highlighting the parts of the fragment that have changed and a small explanation as to why this works when the original one doesn't would make this answer a lot more clear.

Comment: @Shadow the only thing I changed are the attributes `cx` and `cy`. I assumed `cy` was made up of some other elaborate useless function wrappers.

Comment: Thanks - please edit that into your answer and I'll send an upvote your way :)